# Implement this "not in" where clause in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table here where it gets popuplated with ActiveDirectory users every night. This list included generic AD accounts used for a variety of purposes.

*Examples of lastnames of generic accounts:*

- vendor testing
- IT support
- Dept1 Printer
- Visitor1
- Visitor2
- Guest1
- Guest2 and etc

I want to retrieve all records ignoring these records. Something like

```
select * from table where lastname not like '%visitor%'
and lastname not like "%support%"
```

and so on I made this query but it does not do substring comparison.

```
List<String> _ignoreList = new List<String> { "visitor", "test" };
IQueryable<String> _records =
    from _adUserDatas in _adUserDataDBDataContext.ADUserDatas
    where
        _adUserDatas.accountActive.ToLower().Contains("yes")
        && _adUserDatas.staffStudentType.ToLower().Contains("neither")
        && !_ignoreList.Contains(_adUserDatas.lastName)
    orderby _adUserDatas.username
    select _adUserDatas.username;
```

Here's the resulting SQL being sent to SQL Server.

```
{
    SELECT[t0].[username]
    FROM[dbo].[ADUserData] AS[t0]
    WHERE
        (LOWER([t0].[accountActive]) LIKE@ p0)
    AND
        (LOWER([t0].[staffStudentType]) LIKE@ p1)
    AND
        (NOT([t0].[lastName] IN(@p2, @p3)))
    ORDER BY[t0].[username]
}
```

in LINQ query above, it **did not** ignore a record with the lastname "only for testing acct".

Any ideas on how to implement it using LINQ?

I've search the net but nothing came up.

Thanks a lot

Comment: *only for testing acct* doesn't contain the `string` (word) *test* or *visitor*, so it won't be filtered out. You have to add *testing* to your ignore list.

Comment: it does include the word "test" with is a substring of testing.

Comment: Yes, but your query generates an `IN` clause, not a `LIKE` clause. I think bit's answer will generate a `LIKE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Hm.. it could be hard to get to work `like` predicate with `in` clausule.. My solution would be other:

```
var queryable = from _adUserDatas in _adUserDataDBDataContext.ADUserDatas
                where
                    _adUserDatas.accountActive.ToLower().Contains("yes")
                    && _adUserDatas.staffStudentType.ToLower().Contains("neither")
                orderby _adUserDatas.username
                select _adUserDatas.username;

foreach (var ignore in _ignoreList) 
{
     var localIgnore = ignore;
     queryable = queryable.Where(userName => !userName.Contains(localIgnore))
}

var result = queryable.ToList();
```

Comment: Beware, pre-C#5: [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, but it is easy to correct - so it is corrected (introduced local variable). Thanks!

Comment: The field use in the for-loop is the username not the lastname as stated. not going to work as required. but it does give me ideas. thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is because your are checking whether `ignoreList` contains the `LastName`, try doing it the other way.. i.e Whether `LastName` conatins anything from the `ignoreList`..

```
&& !_ignoreList.Any( il => _adUserDatas.lastName.Contains( il ) )
```

This way it will check whether `"only for testing acct"` contains anything from `{ "visitor", "test" }`

Comment: Logically, that's how it should work, but current query providers do not support operations on collections other than `Contains()`. You'll have to build up the query.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from pwas lead me to one that works for my situation. PredicateBuilder which is mentioned in lots of topics here in SOF.com. http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Here's the final code:

```
        ADUserDataDBDataContext _adUserDataDBDataContext = new ADUserDataDBDataContext();

        IQueryable<String> _records = null;

        Expression<Func<ADUserData,Boolean>> _whereClause = PredicateBuilder.True<ADUserData>();

        _whereClause = _whereClause.And(ADUserData => ADUserData.accountActive.ToLower().Contains("yes"));
        foreach (var _item in _ignoreList) 
        {
            _whereClause = _whereClause.And(ADUserData => !ADUserData.lastName.ToLower().Contains(_item));
        }

         _records = _adUserDataDBDataContext.ADUserDatas
            .Where(_whereClause)
            .Select(ADUserData => ADUserData.fan);

        return _records.ToList();
```